# Auto-updating a WordPress installation running under nginx

Tags: nginx, wordpress, update

I seem to have zero trouble running WordPress under nginx, save for any attempts to auto-update WordPress itself. I'm able to update plugins easily. When I attempt this with WordPress core, I'm show a white page.

I checked nginx's error logs and I don't see anything funny, but I may not be looking at the correct logs. Virtualmin points me to an error one and an access log. Neither report any funny business. Googling has yielded little, so I feel this must be something localized to my setup.

Here's what I'm running:
WordPress 3.4
PHP Version: 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.17
MySQL Version: 5.1.63-0ubuntu0.10.04.1
Server Software: nginx/0.7.65

I'm also using W3 Total Cache 0.9.2.4, fwiw.

Should I look at permissions? nginx confs? I think I just need a solid direction, and I can run with it from there.

Comment: You pretty much just need to make sure PHP process has write permission on proper files. Nginx has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

What do you use to process PHP files? Apache or PHP-FPM? Please check the error logs of those (Apache or PHP-FPM).

If that (error log of Apache or PHP-FPM) didn't report anything funny either, enable WordPress logging by adding the following lines in your wp-config.php file...

```
/**
 * This will log all errors notices and warnings to a file called debug.log in
 * wp-content only when WP_DEBUG is true. if Apache does not have write permission, 
 * you may need to create the file first and set the appropriate permissions (i.e. use 666).
 */

define('WP_DEBUG', true); // or false
if (WP_DEBUG) {
  define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
  define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
  @ini_set('display_errors',0);
}
```

If this didn't help either, try posting this in [wordpress.stackexchange.com](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

for PHP-FPM you have to edit the config file to make the user handling the PHP-FPM Daemon

```
nano /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf

user = nginx
group = nginx
```

Then save the file

restart php-fpm daemon also restart nginx to get the changes effect.